# Socket.io and module.exports are not working together. How do I fix this?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am learning Node.js. I just found about module.exports. It seems to me that this is a way to help keep code clean and maintainable by separating code.
I tried out a few examples and it works. I got to console.log a few things by calling the method and it ran the function that was on another file.

I also learned some socket.io. I have got it to work as well.

I wanted to separate the code so I put all the socket.io connection information in a separate file and called the method on the main server file.

It doesn't work. The only way everything works if all the code is on the same page.

This is what I have:

**app.js**

```
    var app = require('express')();
    var ioConnect = require('./ioConnect.js')
    var server = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    server.listen(80);

    ioConnect.ioConnection();
```

**ioConnect.js**

```
    function addScore() {

        var io = require('socket.io');

        io.on('connection', function(socket) {

           socket.on('score', function(data) {
                socket.emit('addScore', 15);
            });

           });
     }



    module.exports.ioConnection = addScore;
```

At first I got an error that said: "io is not defined" so I added 
var io = require('socket.io)(server); and got server is not defined so I tried
var io = require('socket.io'); and got this error:

```
    /root/game/ioConnect2.js:5
                io.on('connection', function(socket) {
                   ^
    TypeError: Object function Server(srv, opts){
      if (!(this instanceof Server)) return new Server(srv, opts);
      if ('object' == typeof srv && !srv.listen) {
        opts = srv;
        srv = null;
      }
      opts = opts || {};
      this.nsps = {};
      this.path(opts.path || '/socket.io');
      this.serveClient(false !== opts.serveClient);
      this.adapter(opts.adapter || Adapter);
      this.origins(opts.origins || '*:*');
      this.sockets = this.of('/');
      if (srv) this.attach(srv, opts);
    } has no method 'on'
        at Object.addScore [as ioConnection] (/root/game/ioConnect2.js:5:16)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/root/game/app:8:19)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
        at startup (node.js:119:16)
        at node.js:906:3
```

If I put the code together on one file everything works. Can someone please explain to me exactly whats going on here and what I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you require socket.io it returns a function. In app.js you called that require/function with an argument and stored the return value in 'io'. Good so far. In ioConnect.js you are storing the function itself in io. rather than do that, you should pass the io you set in app.js to the function returned by your require of ioConnect.js.

## app.js

```
 var app = require('express')();
 var server = require('http').Server(app);
 var io = require('socket.io')(server);
 var ioConnect = require('./ioConnect.js')(io);
 server.listen(80);

 ioConnect.addScore();
```

## ioConnect.js

```
function ioConnection(io) {

    if (!(this instanceof ioConnection)) {
        return new ioConnection(io);
    }

    this.io = io;
}

ioConnection.prototype.addScore = function() {

    this.io.on('connection', function (socket) {

        socket.on('score', function (data) {
            socket.emit('addScore', 15);
        });

    });
}

module.exports = ioConnection;
```

Comment: /root/socket/app.js:4
 var ioConnect = require('./ioConnect.js')(io);
                                          ^
TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: I get an error , it is pointing in between require('./ioConnect.js') and (io)

Comment: Sorry, I should have tested the code before posting, and I hadn't noticed what you were returning in ioConnect.js. I've modified the answer. This is one possible approach. now require ioConnect.js returns a constructor. The constructor takes as an argument the 'io' object, and returns an object that has an addScore method.